# where to store hg extension by default?

Tags: macos, mercurial, path

I'm using mercurial SCM in Mac. I want to add shelve extension to hg. Where to save .py extension file by convention?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By convention, Mercurial extensions are stored in `~/.hgext/`, but you can put them anywhere you want.